# Log4j2 not to create new log file after my application restart

Tags: log4j2

I am using Log4j2. My log file name has time stamp like this: app.${date:yyyy-M-dd_hh-mm-ss}.log.  I have set max file size to 10MB using SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy. We are good as long as application running. After application restart, new log file getting created even though current log file not reached to the max size due to application restart. Is there any way to use the old log file instead of creating new log file after application restart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not with a date in the name. Log4j will resolve the lookup in the name every time the Appender is recreated. There is no way to say "use the date of the newest file that hasn't exceeded the max".

Comment: Thanks rgoers for the immediate reply. Is it possible to use %d option in fileName attribute.

Comment: If you only specify a file pattern without a file name and you use a time based triggering policy and include %d and %i in the pattern then Log4J should do what you are asking for. However, the file will always roll over at the end of the time period even if it hasn’t reached the target size.

Comment: I personally request to allow %d option in fileName attribute, so that Log4j will resolve the name each run.

Comment: Even if it did, it would behave just like ${date:}

Comment: Sorry if I am not clear. I mean Log4j framework has any plans to support this feature in next releases.

Comment: No, there are no plans.